# Capacitor Bluetooth LE not connecting cross platform devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a Bluetooth LE plugin to connect android and iOS devices via bluetooth. Similar platform OS’s(iOS to iOS and Android to Android) can establish connection successfully. However, when trying to connect iOS to Android or Android to iOS, the state of the device remains disconnected and I want to establish the connection between iOS and Android.

Please refer to my sample source code https://github.com/sblsatwikha/TestBluetooth

I have also added the log file in the same repository https://github.com/sblsatwikha/TestBluetooth/blob/main/LogFile

and this is the plugin I integrated following the ReadMe file in
https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le

And I also tried with all the below plugins.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-le

https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble

Comment: What is your specific question? Are you asking for help connecting your devices? We would need more information like a log output and your source code for that. Please [edit] your question and add as much information as possible. Which of the four plugins worked for the connection between the same OS? The last one specifically states it does not work that way.

Comment: Hi @MichaelKotzjan, I have updated with a sample source code I worked on.

Comment: Could you also add the log output you receive? You have a lot of `console.log` calls in your code

Comment: Added the log file here https://github.com/sblsatwikha/TestBluetooth/blob/main/LogFile

Comment: Your log shows that you connected successfully to your iphone: `Connected to device <CBPeripheral: 0x280c70140, identifier = 02FBD040-A36F-5885-BC9C-768135FECA0E, name = iPhone, state = connected>`. Your app did a service discovery afterwards and disconnected. The log also shows that you managed to call `sendBluetoothWriteCommand` but the actual writing command is commented out

Comment: I have run the app in iPhone and has two buttons "Connect" and "Disconnect". Both are working for the iOS devices. The issue is I am not able to connect to the Android devices.